# SQL INSERT INTO from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my table 1:

```
NAME       AGE        SEX        CITY             ID

Clara      22         f          New York         1
Bob        33         m          Washington       2
Sam        25         m          Boston           3
```

this is my table 2:

```
NUMBER       ID
555-1111     1
555-2222     2
555-3333     3
```

and now I want a table 3 which shows me all information:

```
NAME       AGE        SEX        CITY             ID        NUMBER

Clara      22         f          New York         1         555-1111
Bob        33         m          Washington       2         555-2222
Sam        25         m          Boston           3         555-3333
```

I tried first to insert into table 3 only the values from table 1 and then I inserted into table 3 the values from table 2 with an inner join where Id = Id is.

```
INSERT INTO table3 { name, age, sex, city, id}
SELECT name, age, sex, city, id
FROM table 1



INSERT INTO table3 { name, age, sex, city, id, number}
SELECT name, age, sex, city, id, number
FROM table 2 p
INNER JOIN table 3 c ON c.Id = p.Id
```

But all I get is a duplication of my values. instead of having 3 entries, I have like 9 entries, which some have number null, some have only the number and the rest null, and some are correct.

I hope someone can help me

**EDIT**

If I am having now a third Table like this one:

```
NATIONALITY       ID

Canadian          1
American          2
French            3
```

How could I merge all 3 tables into one Table?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You only need one INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable( name, age, sex, city, id, number, nationality)
SELECT name, age, sex, city, s1.id, number, s3.nationality
FROM sourceTable1 s1
INNER JOIN sourceTable2 s2 ON s2.Id = s1.Id
INNER JOIN sourceTable3 s3 ON s3.Id = s1.Id
```

Comment: Works great! But what would I have to do if I am taking values from more than 2 tables? See my Edit

Comment: thanks, that one worked for me. FYI I needed LEFT JOIN because in some  columns I had null values.

Comment: It took me a few seconds to understand this answers. The "table3" from the insert (first) line refers to a different "table3" from the last inner join. I recommend an update of the table names. Maybe in the insert we could have: "destination_table" and on the select and joins "source_table1,2,3". Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest instead of creating a new table, you just use a view that combines the two tables, this way if any of the data in table 1 or table 2 changes, you don't need to update the third table:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
AS
    SELECT  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Sex, t1.City, t1.ID, t2.Number
    FROM    Table1 t1
            INNER JOIN Table2 t2
                ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

If you could have records in one table, and not in the other, then you would need to use a full join:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
AS
    SELECT  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Sex, t1.City, ID = ISNULL(t1.ID, t2.ID), t2.Number
    FROM    Table1 t1
            FULL JOIN Table2 t2
                ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

If you know all records will be in table 1 and only some in table 2, then you should use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
AS
    SELECT  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Sex, t1.City, t1.ID, t2.Number
    FROM    Table1 t1
            LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
                ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

If you know all records will be in table 2 and only some in table 2 then you could use a `RIGHT JOIN`

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
AS
    SELECT  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Sex, t1.City, t2.ID, t2.Number
    FROM    Table1 t1
            RIGHT JOIN Table2 t2
                ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Or just reverse the order of the tables and use a LEFT JOIN (I find this more logical than a right join but it is personal preference):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
AS
    SELECT  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Sex, t1.City, t2.ID, t2.Number
    FROM    Table2 t2
            LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
                ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Comment: Down voter care to comment? I'd be intrigued to hear a good argument as to why a view would not be appropriate, or what is wrong with the views proposed.

Comment: Thats great thank you, but a view isnt neccessary I guess because I wont need the old tables anymore, I am just trying to get everything in one table.

Answer (score 5):

Try doing:

```
INSERT INTO table3(NAME,AGE,SEX,CITY,ID,NUMBER)
SELECT t1.name,t1.age, t1.sex,t1.city,t1.id,t2.number
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

By using LEFT JOIN, this will insert every record from table 1 in table3, and for the ones that match the join condition in table2, it will also insert their number.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an short extension for 3 or more tables to the answer of D Stanley:

```
INSERT INTO other_table (name, age, sex, city, id, number, nationality)
SELECT name, age, sex, city, p.id, number, n.nationality
FROM table_1 p
INNER JOIN table_2 a ON a.id = p.id
INNER JOIN table_3 b ON b.id = p.id
...
INNER JOIN table_n x ON x.id = p.id
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you should be able to do this in one query, joining table1 and table2 together:

```
INSERT INTO table3 { name, age, sex, city, id, number}
SELECT p.name, p.age, p.sex, p.city, p.id, c.number
FROM table1 p
INNER JOIN table2 c ON c.Id = p.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example if multiple tables don't have common Id, you can create yourself, I use `1 as commonId` to create common id so that I can inner join them:

```
Insert Into #TempResult
select CountA, CountB, CountC  from

(
select Count(A_Id) as CountA, 1 as commonId from tableA
  where ....
  and  ...
  and   ...
) as tempA

inner join
(
select Count(B_Id) as CountB, 1 as commonId from tableB
  where ...
  and ...
  and  ...
 ) as tempB

on tempA.commonId = tempB.commonId

inner join
(
select Count(C_ID) as CountC, 1 as commonId from tableC
where ...
and   ...
) as tempC

on tmepB.commonId = tempC.commonId

--view insert result
select * from #TempResult
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the values from 2 tables in a pre-defined way, use a VIEW

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp