# how to insert data to one table from 2 different tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables

```
1.patient table(patientUid,and few fields) 
2.individual table(practiceUid,and few fields).
```

And I have created one table

```
#temp(patientUid,PracticeUid)
```

into which I want to get information from patient table and individual table for the columns in temp table.
I know how to assign value for one particular column from another table column.But I dont know how to assign data for 2 columns from 2 different table columns.

Comment: `insert into #temp(patientUid,PracticeUid) 
select (patientUid,PracticeUid) from patient table` same for other table

Comment: Do you have some relation between the first two tables ? Join them and pick appropriate values to insert in `#temp`. Probably this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404682/sql-insert-into-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 0):

As I didnt get any common column in both table here the query insert all rows from two table separately.

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (patientUid,PracticeUid)
   SELECT patientUid, NULL FROM PatientTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT NULL, PracticeUid FROM IndividualTable
```

If there exist a relation. Then we can use joins.

```
 INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (patientUid,PracticeUid)
       SELECT A.patientUid, B.PracticeUid  FROM PatientTable A
             B.PracticeUid FROM PatientTable A INNER JOIN IndividualTable B
 ON A.CommonColumn = B.CommonColumn
```