# Selecting multiple unrelated data from two tables and insert into one table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, insert-select

This is my scenario

I have a permissions table with the following fields.

```
id | module | permission

1  | client | add
2  | client | edit
3  | client | delete
4  | someth | edit
5  | someth | delete
```

employee table

```
id | status | somestatus
 1 |    act | 1
 2 |    den | 1
 3 |    act | 0
 4 |    den | 1
 5 |    act | 0
 6 |    act | 1
```

Now what i would need to do is select the employee who have status="act" and somestatus=1 and give them all permissions where module="client"

so the table employee_permissions should have these rows

```
id | empid | permid | permvalue
1  | 1     | 1      | 1
2  | 1     | 2      | 1
3  | 1     | 3      | 1
1  | 6     | 1      | 1
2  | 6     | 2      | 1
3  | 6     | 3      | 1
```

This is the query I tried and I'm stuck here

```
INSERT INTO at2_permission_employee (employee_id,permission_id) 
    SELECT at2_employee.employee_id as employee_id
         , (SELECT at2_permission.permission_id as permission_id 
            FROM at2_permission 
            where at2_permission.permission_module='client'
           ) 
    from  at2_employee  
    where at2_employee.employee_status='Active' 
      and at2_employee.employees_served_admin = 1;
```

I get the error sub query returns multiple rows which makes sense to me. But I'm not sure how to modify the query to account for iterating over the rows returned by sub query

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404682/sql-insert-into-from-multiple-tables

Comment: I got to the below but there's an issue near 'from' INSERT INTO employee_permissions (empid,permid) 
(SELECT at2_permission.permission as permid FROM at2_permission where at2_permission.module='client')
FROM at2_employee AS p
INNER JOIN at2_permission c ON c.Id = p.Id
INNER JOIN employee_permissions n ON n.Id = p.Id 
WHERE at2_employee.status='Act' and at2_employee.somestatus  = 1;

Comment: 'Status' is a keyword so you might want to change the field name

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, like this:

```
INSERT INTO at2_permission_employee (employee_id, permission_id, permvalue)
SELECT 
  at2_employee.employee_id, 
  at2_permission.permission_id, 
  1  
FROM at2_permission cross join at2_employee
WHERE
  at2_employee.employee_status='Active' 
  and at2_employee.employees_served_admin = 1
  and at2_permission.permission_module='client';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear where the value for `permvalue` should come from so I hard coded it and used the `permission.id` for both `id` and `permid`, but this query should give you an idea on how to accomplish what you want:

```
insert employee_permissions (id, empid, permid, permvalue)
select p.id, e.id, p.id, 1
from employee e, permissions p
where p.module = 'client' and e.status = 'act' and e.somestatus = 1;
```