# Insert values using 2 different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a new table in SQL using 2 different tables from same database. I tried using Union All but it gives me an error since there needs to be a equal number of columns for union. Is there any way o do this without Union ALL? Can someone please show me the correct way to do it. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
INSERT [Data].[dbo].[Name] (Id, PlateId,RecommendationId,PositionId, Min, Max)

SELECT id
, pid
, tid
, min
, max
FROM [Users].[dbo].[Settings]
UNION ALL
SELECT tid
FROM [Users].[dbo].[Tips]
```

Comment: What do you expect getting inserted for the missing columns in the second part of the union? Also, I recommend changing the names of, well, everything in your tables. You'll thank me 18 months from now, when you need to do some maintenance and struggle to understand what is `pid` and how it is different then `tid`.

Comment: Is there a FK on your second table?

Comment: [Hope this helps you , Please checkout the details on the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404682/sql-insert-into-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have an equal number of columns in both tables you can select a literal as a placeholder for each missing column.

```
INSERT [Data].[dbo].[Name] (Id, PlateId,RecommendationId,PositionId, Min, Max)

SELECT id
, pid
, tid
, min
, max
FROM [Users].[dbo].[Settings]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' AS id
, 'x' AS pid
, tid
, 0  AS min
, 0  AS max
FROM [Users].[dbo].[Tips]
```

Whatever it is you use for your values, there needs to be the same number of columns for both selects in a union.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UNIONing all the columns from both tables, get a specific list of all the columns you wish to include:

```
INSERT [Data].[dbo].[Name] (Id, PlateId, RecommendationId, PositionId, Min, Max)
    SELECT 
        id, pid, tid, min, max
    FROM 
        [Users].[dbo].[Settings]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        id, pid, tid, min, max
    FROM 
        [Users].[dbo].[Tips]
```

If one of the columns you wish to include only appears in one table, you can use a NULL or static value for that column, on that table (for instance) `,NULL AS [pid]` or `,'' as [pid]`.