# Insert into Table from multiple sources simultaneously - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, insert-into

I need to insert data to a table from **4 different sources**. Approx 2M rows **per source**.
I'm doing it with 4 different **procedures** and I don't want to change it.

Is there any problem in **inserting** it simultaneously?

```
Insert into TableA
Select * 
From  TableB

Insert into TableA
Select * 
From  TableC

Insert into TableA
Select * 
From  TableD

Insert into TableA
Select * 
From  TableE
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: The only issue I can see would be with a Primary key if not a sequence, or not a natrual key. If you're using select max(ID)+1 you may run into concurrency issues.

Comment: I don't think there are any problems; though I would do it in a (single) transaction.

Comment: I'm not using max(ID) and also the TableA does not have a primary Key.

Comment: Then I see no issues if no PK.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20404789/6371926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of option you can try.

1. Batched Operation: Select * from table1 is not a good approach as it can create a implicit lock on the table.
   Bring the data in batches. Finding the right batch size has to be worked out with a few trials but I believe a batch size of 30-50K should be ok.
2. Option is to use SSIS packages, most of the processing complexity is take care of you so you should be able get the ground running quickly and if its a frequently reused then create SQL job and let the package be called.

A few reference links to get your head spinning

a) [SSIS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59193/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-insert-large-numbers-of-rows)
b) [Batch](http://sqlserverplanet.com/data-warehouse/transferring-large-amounts-of-data-using-batch-inserts)

Use me -> Google