# PostgreSQL Insert Query Results from Two Tables Into a New Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a supplied_services table:

```
id | user_id | supplied_service_name
1  | 1       | English Translations
2  | 2       | English Teaching
3  | 3       | English Teaching
```

I have a needed_services table:

```
id | user_id | needed_service_name
1  | 4       | English Teaching
2  | 5       | English Translations
3  | 5       | English Teaching
```

There is a matches table that is supposed to match the suppliers with the needers. My SQL is ([SQL INSERT INTO from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404682/sql-insert-into-from-multiple-tables)):

```
insert into matches (
    user_needer,
    user_supplier,
    needed_service_name,
    supplied_service_name
    )
select ns.user_id,
    ss.user_id,
    needed_service_name,
    supplied_service_name
from supplied_services ss
inner join needed_services ns on ss.supplied_service_name = ns.needed_service_name
```

The output should be this:

```
id | user_needer | user_supplier | needed_service_name |supplied_service_name
1  | 1           | 5             | English Translations|English Translations
2  | 3           | 4             | English Teaching    | English Teaching
3  | 8           | 7             | English Teaching    | English Teaching
4  | 2           | 5             | English Teaching    | English Teaching
5  | 3           | 5             | English Teaching    | English Teaching
```

However, the output is this:

```
id | user_needer | user_supplier | needed_service_name |supplied_service_name
1  | 1           | 5             | English Translations|English Translations
2  | 3           | 4             | English Teaching    | English Teaching
3  | 8           | 7             | English Teaching    | English Teaching
```

After it gets a match, it doesn't look for any other matches. How can I fix the SQL so that it will output the correct table?

Comment: I tried your SQL and the matches table is created as expected. Could you post your DDL, DML and SELECT queries?

Comment: Check http://rextester.com/ESC81975. I don't know where the users 8 and 7 came from. I assume you haven't showed all data in the 2 source tables.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My example had some columns removed for simplicity and it appears those other columns could have affected the result. I will test those other columns on the rextester link you provided later